# Login with security key doesn't work Windows 11

Tags: windows, authentication, security, windows-11, yubico

```
I bought a security key from Yubico and I want to use it to log into Windows 11 but I don't want to use the Yubico software. I know windows can do it, but it doesn't work in the settings, I set everything and the program has to enter a password and it doesn't ask me for a key.
[1screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Sq79.png)
[2screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhExz.png)
[3screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrlDO.png)
```

I want it to ask me to insert the key into the PC and then on the PIN alle it does not work.